# Separated websocket for each connected client

Tags: java, javascript, networking, websocket

I am planing to develop JavaScript client application that will connect to Java server using websocket. Server should handle many connected clients.
After some reading I found out websocket single thread. This is not good if I want to run databases query that can block everything for a while.

What I am thinking about is to opening separated websocket for each JavaScript client. One socket is listening for new connection and when connection is established creates some unique id. After that opens new websocket and send id to client using listener socket. When client received id close first socket and connect to new one.

What do you think, is it good solution? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Not an answer, just an idea, have you considered Node.js? Is javascript, I know, but you have stuff like Sails(http://sailsjs.org/#!) that make CRUD operations in a REST way with websockets. All just by doing sails new <project_name>.

Comment: Websockets are neither single nor multithreaded, they are just a protocol. Implementations of them are affected by threading limitations. If your Java Websocket implementation can only be used from a single thread then move to another implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 4 gives you the chance to use a thread pool. The documentation is here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Akka](http://akka.io/) to manage all the concurrency and thread management for you. Or you could use the [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) that already builds on Akka and that supports WebSocket quite nicely. With Play you can choose between Java and Scala on the server side.

Answer (score -2):

You should use NodeJS on the server to handle the socket i/o.  You can connect to it via your javascript client apps, and then make calls to your Java based API.  NodeJS is non blocking (async) and you should be able to leverage your existing Javascripting skills to quickly build a Node app.  You could even use a full MEAN stack to build the client/server app.  http://meanjs.org/ or http://mean.io/#!/ are two popular places to start.